# What's a Java alternative to Google App Engine for developing iPhone Push Notification services?

Tags: java, iphone, google-app-engine, hosting, push-notification

I'm a Java programmer who is working on an iPhone application. I'd like it to use Push Notification services.

I originally thought I could use Google App Engine to provide the payloads to Apple, but I see now that it won't be possible because App Engine doesn't support the low-level socket programming that is needed to communicate with Apple.

Are there any alternatives to Google App Engine that let me use Java?

In brief, I'm wondering if there is a free hosting platform that supports Java and Socket Programming

UPDATE - since writing this question I've written an app that uses Urban Airship to act as a middleman between GAE and APNS. It works just swell. There is an app engine issue on this - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1164 if you'd like to follow, but personally I've decided that this isn't really something that GAE should be doing. Just use Urban Airship.

Comment: What features of GAE are you looking to replicate?  There is nothing exactly like GAE, but there are shared hosting platforms.

Comment: I am slightly aware of other GAE features such as a non-relational database. I think the main goal though is to have free Java hosting with Socket programming. Some kind of persistence is required as well, whether it's like what Google offers or a MySQL db, or whatever.

Comment: I assume the key word here is "free".  I don't know of any free Java hosting providers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/push/) provide RESTful web services for sending iPhone push notifications. [This cookbook example](http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/googleappengine-python-with-urbanairship-to-send-out-iphone-os30-push-notifications/?id=ahJhcHBlbmdpbmUtY29va2Jvb2tyvAELEgtSZWNpcGVJbmRleCJPYWhKaGNIQmxibWRwYm1VdFkyOXZhMkp2YjJ0eUpRc1NDRU5oZEdWbmIzSjVJaGROWVhOb2RYQnpJSGRwZEdnZ1FYQndJRVZ1WjJsdVpRdwwLEgZSZWNpcGUiUGFoSmhjSEJsYm1kcGJtVXRZMjl2YTJKdmIydHlKUXNTQ0VOaGRHVm5iM0o1SWhkTllYTm9kWEJ6SUhkcGRHZ2dRWEJ3SUVWdVoybHVaUXc2DA) shows how to use it from GAE using Python; I assume this can be done in Java also.

Comment: This may be useful, thanks. I recall hearing at an iPhone Developer's meetup that a few startups were getting ready to help developers who wanted to do Push Notifications.

Comment: Wow, this feels old. Anyway, Urban Airship is what I wound up going with and I don't have a single complaint! Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though as yet it's vaporware, keep an eye on [App Notify](http://appnotify.com/) as well. Urban Airship looks pretty cool, but doing the math in my head, I'd end up paying them hundreds of dollars a month for an app that I'd have a hard time selling for more than $0.99.

Answer (score 1):

Like Justin said (thanks random evangelist), [AppNotify](http://appnotify.com) is launching nearer to the end of this month.  We're just finishing up a few admin screens and doing some final tests.  The pricing will be better structured than Urban Airship, and with a much better interface.

If you want something in particular or more info, send me an email personally at adam.m@selectstartstudios.com

We're using it to develop our own products, but if we've missed a corner case I'd like to know about it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself with an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) cluster. They have a nice Eclipse plugin for easily spawning Tomcat instances and remote debugging Java applications.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check and follow these guys. It seems they are working on different stuff onto APNS integration. check out ns4app

Edit : They are changed their names and products ? forget my previous link. Check out [MonoPush Project](http://monopush.com)