# How to schedule repeating Apple push notifications?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am wondering if it is possible to setup repeating push notifications. The reason I want to do this is to allow my users to schedule a daily reminder at a particular time. Is this possible? Currently the only options I can think of are:

- schedule a lot of notifications, say one each for the next 30 days. Then "top up" the notifications every time the app is launched
- allow the user's to only pick specific times (eg. 1am, 2am, 3am), and then have a service runs once per hour and sends out batch notifications to devices that have registered for that timeslot.

I am planning to use the Urban Airship platform, but am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurring notifications are not currently supported by any of the major service providers (Airship, iLime, App Notify). iLime and App Notify are rolling out this feature in some form soon, Airship is not (at least in the near future). All of this is based on direct correspondence with these companies. I suggest either implementing the scheduling part on your own server using cron jobs and then sending the push request to Urban Airship (or whomever you choose) using code like this: http://bitbucket.org/urbanairship/push_sample/

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look [What's a Java alternative to Google App Engine for developing iPhone Push Notification services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196705/whats-a-java-alternative-to-google-app-engine-for-developing-iphone-push-notific/2448009#2448009)